# angular 4 Array Push data is not updated instantly on the view

Tags: arrays, angular

I am updating the  data on the array in component and in the same method trying to calculate the width of the Dom element .But the dom element width is not setting properly because the dom is not getting updated until the method is done. I have created a project in plunker. Can anyone look into the project and help me on the issue.

Link to plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/2uIpzdnprwtFoab3YA8s?p=preview

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit,
  ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './../app.view.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

  @Input() topicPeopleTextBoxWidth : number;

  peopleNoOfRows : number = 1;

  @ViewChild('topicPeopleSelcted') topicPeopleSelectedView: ElementRef;

  @Input() topicPeoples : Array<Object> = new Array<Object>();

  //In the method i should create a span of the input that entered in the textbox 
  //and set the size of the text Box according to the size of the span.

  //The problem currently happening is once the Array gets updated it not updated the span 
  // and one i try to get the width of the span its not returning correctly.

  setPeopleWidth(event,inputValue) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
       this.topicPeoples.push({
        "name": inputValue
      });
      console.log(this.topicPeopleSelectedView.nativeElement.offsetWidth);
      let childrens = this.topicPeopleSelectedView.nativeElement.children;
      let peopleDiv = childrens[0];
      let textBoxDiv = childrens[1];
      let peopleSpan = peopleDiv.children;
      let totalSpanWidth = 0;
      for (var _i = 0; _i < peopleSpan.length; _i++) {
        totalSpanWidth = totalSpanWidth + peopleSpan[_i].offsetWidth;
      }
      console.log(this.topicPeopleTextBoxWidth);
      console.log(totalSpanWidth);
      if (420 - totalSpanWidth > 0) {
        this.topicPeopleTextBoxWidth = 420 - totalSpanWidth;
      }
      console.log(this.topicPeopleTextBoxWidth);
    }
  }
}

<div id="searchBar" class="input-form">
        <label class="label-form">people In Topic</label>
        <div id="topicPeople" #topicPeopleSelcted style="border-bottom: 1px #e6e6e6;padding:0px;">
            <span style="padding:0px;">
                <span 
                  *ngFor="let person of topicPeoples" style="background-color: #e6e6e6;font-color:black;"> 
                  {{ person.name }} </span>
            </span>
            <textarea  (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()" [style.width.px]="topicPeopleTextBoxWidth+'px'" rows="1" id="topicPeopleTextBox"
                       style="border:none;" (keyup)="setPeopleWidth($event,topicPeopleHash.value);" #topicPeopleHash value="{{topicPeople}}"
                       spellcheck="false" autocomplete="false" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" tabindex="1" dir="ltr" aria-autocomplete="list"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Regards,
M.Amarnath

Answer (score 0):

As a fast fix I suggest to wrap your calculation code into:

`setTimeout(() => { // YOUR CODE HERE });`

It will make your code execute after DOM changes will be applied. I've tried it in your plunker and it worked.

Comment: Thanks .. it worked. I have one question why should we do it?.How did the method helped in solving the issue

Comment: It's quite long talk. You can read about it here: http://voidcanvas.com/setimmediate-vs-nexttick-vs-settimeout/. In 2 words: there's reflow and repaint happening each browser tick. setTimeout will queue your function for the next tick. That means reflow will happen before and your DOM geometry will be recalculated by that time.